# How to reinitialize dataTables with newly fetched data from server using ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

So here I have list of menus for admin and under them I have Upload news. When this particular menu is clicked, I call a partial view as below.

```
$("#body_data").load("/Admin/GetDailyNews", function () {
          $("#dailyNews").dataTable({
                    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                    "columnDefs": [{ "targets": 3, "orderable": false }],
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "" },
                    "deferRender": true
          });
}
```

My PartialViewResult in AdminController is as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetDailyNews()
{
     var context=new MyContext();
     List<AVmodel.NewsEventsViewModel> model = new List<AVmodel.NewsEventsViewModel>();
     List<news> news = (from n in context.news where n.stdate >= System.DateTime.Now orderby n.stdate descending select n).ToList();
     foreach (var NEWS in news)
     {
          model.Add(new AVmodel.NewsEventsViewModel()
          {
               EDate = NEWS.stdate,
               EDesc = NEWS.brief,
               EName = Convert.ToString(NEWS.name),
               NID = NEWS.nid
          });
     }
     return PartialView("_UploadNews", model);
}
```

My _UploadNews.cshtml is as below

```
@model IEnumerable<MCB.Models.BusinessObjects.AVmodel.NewsEventsViewModel>
<table id="dailyNews" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-bordered order-column">
     <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Event Date</th>
               <th>Event Name</th>
               <th>Detailed News</th>
               <th class="disabled">Actions</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          @foreach (var news in Model)
          {
               <tr data-row="row_@news.NID">
                   <td>@news.EDate.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                   <td>@Convert.ToString(news.EName)</td>
                   <td>@Convert.ToString(news.EDesc)</td>
                   <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#editAddNews" data-toggle="modal" onclick="javascript: EditNews(this);" data-info="data_@news.NID"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> </button>&nbsp; <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="javascript: DeleteNews(this);" data-info="data_@news.NID"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></button></td>
               </tr>
          }
     </tbody>
</table>
```

So till now it's good. Everything is going well and the table displays only  those news which are of future days. Now I have a option for admin to fetch the whole set of news from table, including past days. So I have kept a checkbox in my partialview as below which is a **bootstrap switch type**:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fetchNews-checkbox" data-on-text="All News" data-off-text="Upcoming News" data-on-color="primary" data-off-color="default" data-label-width="100px" data-label-text="News details">
```

and I have written a `onswitchchange` for that particular checkbox as below:

```
$("[name='fetchNews-checkbox']").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
     if (state) 
     {
           fetchNews('all');
     }
     else 
     {
           fetchNews('upcoming');
     }
});
```

and my `fetchNews` function is as below:

```
function fetchNews(context)
{
    if(context!="")
    {
        $("#dailyNews").dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Admin/FetchNews"
        });
    }
}
```

when this function is called I am getting an alert which says

> DataTables warning: table id=dailyNews - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

I visited the above said link but was not able to understand anything. Can anyone please let me know, **how to call a controller json method and render list of news into this Table?**

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The error message http://datatables.net/tn/3 states the problem precisely. You're re-initializing the table with different options in `fetchNews()`.

You need to destroy the table first, see http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3#destroy. 
You can do that with `$("#dailyNews").dataTable().fnDestroy()` (DataTables 1.9.x) or `$("#dailyNews").DataTable().destroy()` (DataTables 1.10.x).

```
function fetchNews(context)
{
     if(context!="")
     {
        // Destroy the table
        // Use $("#dailyNews").DataTable().destroy() for DataTables 1.10.x
        $("#dailyNews").dataTable().fnDestroy()

        $("#dailyNews").dataTable({
           // ... skipped ...
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using DataTables 1.10.x, you can initialize the new table with additional option `"destroy": true`, see below.

```
function fetchNews(context)
{
     if(context!="")
     {
        $("#dailyNews").dataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            // ... skipped ...
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 62):

**This worked for me after a lot of research**:- First check if dataTable exist or not,
if does destroy the dataTable and then recreate it

```js
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#mytable")) {
  $('#mytable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
}

$("#mytable").dataTable({...
                       
                });
```

Comment: it's not working for me 
my datatable version is 1.9.4
I am not able to re intialized it in Angular JS

Comment: I'm lacking `.clear()` in my code for it to works! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Datatables has a retrieve option. If your table receive other content after inicialization you can set the parameter: retrieve: true,

You can watch the documentation here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve

```
$("#body_data").load("/Admin/GetDailyNews", function () {
      $("#dailyNews").dataTable({
                retrieve: true,
                "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "columnDefs": [{ "targets": 3, "orderable": false }],
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "" },
                "deferRender": true
      });
```

}

Comment: Is this something new option added with datatable? If yes please attach the source along with datatables version too.. :) It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 3):

$('#mytable').DataTable().destroy();
$('#mytable').html('');

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation for your code.

Answer (score 3):

While above answers treat the symptom (*'Cannot re-initialize'* warning) they do not address the root cause of the problem: you **shall not** populate DataTable from within jQuery `$.load()`/`$.ajax()`/`$.get()`/`$.post()` success callbacks, because it raises all sorts of issues caused by async AJAX-call nature.

By invoking DataTables `.destroy()` method you can make things even worse, as each time you retrieve the data from the server you unnecessarily destroy and create anew your DataTable which is a waste of performance at the very least.

**Instead**, you should make use of DataTables [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option which triggers AJAX-call where and when it is necessary allowing you to fully benefit from DataTables API methods and not screwing the performance, e.g to re-fetch your data you simply do [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()), if you need to change URL before loading up to date data, you do [`ajax.url().load()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load())

The complete live **DEMO** of OP's example might have looked as simple as that:

```js
//initialize DataTables
const dataTable = $('#newsTable').DataTable({
 //specify AJAX source, params and response source
 ajax: {
  url: 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything',
  data: () => ({
    q: ($('input[name="subject"]:checked').val() || 'javascript'),
    language: 'en',
    apiKey: '699ba21673cd45aba406b1984b480b60'
  }),
  dataSrc: 'articles'
 },
 //set up table columns
 columns: [
  {title: 'Source', data: 'source.name'},
  {title: 'Title', data: 'title'},
  {title: 'Content', data: 'content'}
 ]
});

//trigger table data re-fetch with new subject
$('input[name="subject"]').on('change', () => dataTable.ajax.reload())
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <label>Pick the subject:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="subject" value="python">python</input>
  <input type="radio" name="subject" value="javascript">javascript</input>
  <table id="newsTable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can reinitialize the data table everytime by providing the destroy property as show below:

```
            .done(function(ret){
                $("#cloud").DataTable({
                   ordering : true,
                   pageLength : 20,
                   destroy: true,
                   data : loadData(ret)
                })
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after a lot of research:
$('#userList').DataTable().clear().destroy();

Answer (score 0):

This will reload datatable with fresh content.

```
$("#dailyNews").dataTable().ajax.reload();
```