# "Search" and "Pagination" on Table are missing after converting to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, html-table

Can anyone here help me to solve my problem?

BEFORE converting to AJAX:

[image]

AFTER converting to AJAX:

[image]

and you will notice that on the first image there are 5,000+ records only 10 records per tab. On the second image there are only 20 records BUT if the code will work it must only 10 records per page will be shown.

I'll provide a code below so that you can check it and tell me where part of the code that I missed.

MY CODE

view.php

```js
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- DATA TABLE SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/table.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function load(){
     
     // AJAX for loading view table
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("loadTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
         }
     };
     xhttp.open("GET", "table/loadViewTable.php", true);
     xhttp.send();
 }
</script>
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="table-responsive">
     <div id="loadTable" >
         
     </div>
 </div>                                                          
</div>
</body>
```

loadViewTable.php

```html
<?php
 include_once '..\assets\function\retrieveFunction.php';
 $loadStudList = array();
    $loadStudList = currentEnrolledStudentsList();
?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="claimTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>School Semester</th>
            <th>Student Number</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Middlename</th>
            <th>Suffixname</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Year Level</th>
            <th>Registration Date</th>
            <th>Encoder</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
     $i=0; 
     for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){?>
     <tr onclick="getClaimData()">
      <td><?php echo $i;?></td>     
      <td>2017-2016-1</td>     
      <td>123456789</td>     
      <td>Doe</td>     
      <td>John</td>     
      <td>Anyone</td>     
      <td>NONE</td>     
      <td>BSMAR-E</td>     
      <td>4TH</td>     
      <td>12/11/2017</td>     
      <td>JOHN</td>     
     </tr>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the purpose is when I'm using PHP+HTML for loading the 5,000+ records it takes 10-15 seconds on my PC and it takes 20-30 seconds loading time on other low end PC's but when I use AJAX it takes only 3-5 seconds to load all records but the search bar and pagination are missing.

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to add this code...

```js
function getClaimData(){

    var table = $('#claimTable').DataTable();
    $('#claimTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        document.getElementById("claimStudID").value = data[1];
        document.getElementById("claimStudLN").value = data[2];
        document.getElementById("claimStudFN").value = data[3];
        document.getElementById("claimStudMN").value = data[4];
        document.getElementById("claimSuffix").value = data[5];
        document.getElementById("claimStudCourse").value = data[6];
        document.getElementById("claimStudLevel").value = data[7];
    } );
}
```

after I type my query all table will show but no search and pagination but when I will clicked the table all features of the table worked.

BEFORE clicking the table
[image]

AFTER
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

For better explanation I uploaded my file. Please test it
https://www.4shared.com/s/fHFrxPNtuca

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to re-initialize the table once the ajax call is complete:

```
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#mytable")) {
    $('#mytable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
}

$("#mytable").dataTable();
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42088677/3310235) for more information

**UPDATE AFTER QUESTION CHANGED**

You seem  to have your datatable loading fine, I can see the pagination. For a better approach, fetch the claims data as json from the server, and let datatables load the table for you:

**claims.php**

```
$claims_array = array(....);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($claims_array);
```

**tables.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '/claims.php' // This is from our json endpoint above
    });
});
```

See [Ajax Sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) from Datatables

Comment: awesome :), though from a better approach point of view, you can return the data json using `json_encode($claim_data)` using ajax and let datatables do the magic

Comment: I tested your code but I don't know if I'm doing right... this part of code where will I put it? "$('#example').DataTable( {" on the main page? or on the loadViewTable.php? btw I updated again my post.