# Cannot reinitialise jquery DataTable for child tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am getting this
[Cannot reinitialize datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ngGh.png) error when i try to open the child table keeping first child table open.
I tried many ways 
1) 'destroy':true
2) 'bdestroy':true
3) table.destroy()
4) table.api().destroy()

but this all has some negative effects.
and the two different table with the same id gets generated each and every time Please suggest a sure short solution for this. Thanks in advance.
My Code is

For Parent:

```
 tblMemberMappingRule = $("#datatable_MemberMappingRule").DataTable({
    "serverSide": false,
    "filter": true,
    "bDestory": true,
    //"bStateSave": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/MemberMappingRule/GetAllMemberMappingRuleField",
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
    "stateSave": true,
    "bSearchable": true,
    "order": [[7, "desc"]],
    "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
        $('a, .btn').tooltip();
        $("#datatable_MemberMappingRule").DataTable().rows().every(function () {
            var data = this.data();
            if (sessionStorage.getItem("expandedTableId") == JSON.stringify(data.fkMemberMappingRuleFieldID)) {
            var tr = $(this.node());
            this.child(format(tr.data('details-control'))).show();
            //varMemberMappingRuleFieldID = id;              
                varMemberMappingRuleFieldID = JSON.stringify(data.fkMemberMappingRuleFieldID);
                onRowDetailsClick.call(this, tblMemberMappingRule);

            tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        });

    },
    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
        $('a, .btn').tooltip();
        $("#datatable_MemberMappingRule").DataTable().rows().every(function () {
            var data = this.data();
            if (sessionStorage.getItem("expandedTableId") == JSON.stringify(data.fkMemberMappingRuleFieldID)) {
                var tr = $(this.node());
                this.child(format(tr.data('details-control'))).show();
                //varMemberMappingRuleFieldID = id;              
                varMemberMappingRuleFieldID = JSON.stringify(data.fkMemberMappingRuleFieldID);
                onRowDetailsClick.call(this, tblMemberMappingRule);

                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        });
    },
    "columns": [

        { "data": "Action", "title": "Action" },
        { "data": "PayerName", "title": "Parent Health Plan" },
        { "data": "HealthPlan", "title": "Health Plan" },
        { "data": "LOB", "title": "LOB" },
        { "data": "Product", "title": "Product" },
        { "data": "PlanCategory", "title": "Plan Category" },
        //{ "data": "Actions", "title": "Actions" },
        //{ "data": "ReplaceWith", "title": "Add/replace/delete with" },
        //{ "data": "Position", "title": "Position" },
        //{ "data": "Characters", "title": "Characters" },
        { "data": "SourceMemberID", "title": "Source Member ID" },
        //{ "data": "RuleSequenceNumber", "title": "Rule Sequence Number" },
        { "data": "EffectiveDate", "title": "Effective Date" },
        { "data": "TermDate", "title": "Term Date" },
        { "data": "CreatedBy", "title": "Created By", "class": "hideCol" },
        { "data": "CreatedDate", "title": "Created Date", "class": "hideCol" },
        { "data": "UpdatedBy", "title": "Updated By", "class": "hideCol" },
        { "data": "UpdatedDate", "title": "Updated Date", "class": "hideCol" }
    ],
    'colVis': {
        'buttonText': 'Columns',
        'overlayFade': 0,
        'exclude': [0],
        "activate": "mouseover"
    },
    "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 0,
        "orderable": false,
        "className": 'text-center width150'
    }]

});
```

For Child :

```
function onRowDetailsClick(tbl) {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = tbl.row(tr);
    var idx = $.inArray(tr.attr('id'), detailRows);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        tr.removeClass('details');
        row.child.hide();
        // Remove from the 'open' array
        detailRows.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
        tr.addClass('details');
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        // Child datatable for matching membermappingrule records
        tblMemberMappingRuleField = $("#datatable_MemberMappingRuleChild").DataTable({
            "rowReorder": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "filter": true,
            "bDestory": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/MemberMappingRule/GetAllMemberMappingRuleByFieldId",
                "data": { fkMemberMappingRuleFieldID: varMemberMappingRuleFieldID },
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "bSearchable": true,
            "order": [[7, "asc"]],
            "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
                $('a, .btn').tooltip();
            },
            "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                $('a, .btn').tooltip();
            },
            "columns": [

                { "data": "Action", "title": "Action" },
                { "data": "SwapAction", "title": "Swap Action" },
        { "data": "Actions", "title": "Actions" },
        { "data": "ReplaceWith", "title": "Add/replace/delete with" },
        { "data": "Position", "title": "Position" },
        { "data": "Characters", "title": "Characters" },
        { "data": "SourceMemberID", "title": "Source Member ID" },
        { "data": "RuleSequenceNumber", "title": "Rule Sequence Number" },
        { "data": "EffectiveDate", "title": "Effective Date" },
        { "data": "TermDate", "title": "Term Date" },
        { "data": "CreatedBy", "title": "Created By", "class": "hideCol" },
        { "data": "CreatedDate", "title": "Created Date", "class": "hideCol" },
        { "data": "UpdatedBy", "title": "Updated By", "class": "hideCol" },
        { "data": "UpdatedDate", "title": "Updated Date", "class": "hideCol" }
            ],
            'colVis': {
                'buttonText': 'Columns',
                'overlayFade': 0,
                'exclude': [0],
                "activate": "mouseover"
            },
            "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [0, 1],
                "orderable": false,
                "className": 'text-center width100'
            }]
        });

        ShowHideColumn();
        // Add to the 'open' array
        if (idx === -1) {
            detailRows.push(tr.attr('id'));
            //sessionStorage.setItem("detailRows", detailRows);
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(detailRows));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinitialize dataTables with newly fetched data from server using ajax in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150480/how-to-reinitialize-datatables-with-newly-fetched-data-from-server-using-ajax-in)

Comment: No, i had gone through this solution already. it is replacing my first child's table causing to display inappropriate data,  rather than allowing me to initialize the second table properly

Comment: Found a fix, generated table id dynamically.. don't know whether it is a proper way to solve this issue or not.