# jOuery DataTables: data is visible after click on column name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a question about [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables):

I receive the data from my REST API.
After page loading I have empty table, my data appears after clicking on one of column names or on Show (combobox with number) entries.

Do You know why table showing data only after click on one of available buttons?
If I remove last column from table with delete button - table showing data without clicking on column name after page load, so probably there's something wrong with last column definition

this is my js:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/user/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                bindtoDatatable(data);
            }
        });

    });

    function bindtoDatatable(data) {
        var table = $('#table').dataTable({
            data: data,
            columns: [{
                data: "id"
            }, {
                data: "firstname"
            }, {
                data: "lastname"
            }, {
                data: "email"
            }, {
                data: null,
                className: "center",
                defaultContent: '<a href="" class="deleteUser">Delete</a>'
            }]
        })
    }

    //Delete a record
    $('.deleteUser').on('click', 'a.deleteUser', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        table.remove( $(this).closest('tr'), {
            title: 'Delete record',
            message: 'Are you sure you wish to remove this record?',
            buttons: 'Delete'
        } );
    }
    );
```

and html:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../js/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/main.css">
        <script src="../../../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../js/admin/users2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
                src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <title>Admin: users page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Administration
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/admin/users">Users</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="../index">Log out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <table id="table" class="display">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>firstname</th>
                    <th>lastname</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option to populate your datatable. Populating the table with *externally* called jQuery `.ajax()` causes different sorts of issues - see details in one of my [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56688673/11299053) along with example (btw, if that answer helps to sort things out for you, upvote is greatly welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

ok, i missed one column in my html for actions button
after add actions to table - everything works